# How does the GE H75 eliminate the need for hot section inspections?

Tags: turboprop

Operators of the [Pratt & Whitney Canada PT6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_Canada_PT6) will be familiar with the need for hot section inspections half way to TBO. General Electric is touting the lack of hot section inspection requirements for their [GE H75](http://www.geaviation.com/engines/docs/bga/datasheet-h75.pdf) engine. How did GE eliminate the need for the added inspections?

Comment: It looks like they use single piece rotors where the PT-6 uses blades connected to a central hub to form the rotor. They also use more forgiving metals like titanium.

Answer (score 1):

this is because the fact that GE H series engines do not have fuel nozzles and feed fuel into combustion chamber through a rotating shaft. this design is much less sensitive to the fuel quality and combustion deposits in comparison with usual fuel nozzles